# HERE map Marker Clustering using custom image

Tags: android, sdk, here-api

Is there anyway I can customize the cluster image and show the numbers in a different way?

I am using the ImageClusterStyle class. But it doesn't show how many items in that cluster.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the only option to get that result is to build the image yourself. If you use [BasicClusterStyle](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-cluster-basicclusterstyle.html) you get the number of items but not the image and if you use [ImageClusterStyle](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-cluster-imageclusterstyle.html), as you mentioned, you get the image but no number.

I recommend creating a bitmap using a canvas with shapes on top.

Comment: So if I use canvas to draw image and shapes, does it show the number of items in a cluster?

Comment: No. What I meant is that you draw the number yourself as part of the image using, for example, canvas.drawText https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Here's what I did. I created a bitmap and draw a number on top of it and assigned it to each ImageClusterStyle I created. 

For example I have a total range of 100 markers then for each count of markers I created an ImageClusterStyle and assigned it to Theme.